# Is there any way to convert the hexcode back to SHA256 object?

Tags: python, hash, digital-signature, sha256

How to convet hexcode produced from SHA256 back to the SHA256 object ?

```
digest = SHA256.new()      # digest empty
digest.update(str(data).encode())   # digest has string hashed
hex_code = digest.hexcode()
```

hexcode contains the digest of the data , now is there any way to convert the hexcode back to the SHA256 object ?

Is there any method to use the hexcode to generate the original digest object?

```
'print(digest) gives
 <Crypto.Hash.SHA256.SHA256Hash object at 0x7fc2e2ea4da0>
print(digest.hexcode()) gives
bc273cf180e376f52d8c8a7f6b6ffd5babb872629e5fcc4685fe5284887faee'
```

Is there any way to use the digest.hexcode() and generate the hash object ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a strong function for hash strings and restore it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476217/a-strong-function-for-hash-strings-and-restore-it)

Comment: Basically, you want to restore *the state* of `digest` from `hex_code` so you could continue to `update` it?

Comment: With some caveats, the answer is: **NO**